# No UIViewController supplied to the ad. Cannot continue

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, admob, interstitial

I have a sprite-kit game, and the first ad loads on `gameOver`, but the following `gameOver`'s after that give the following error :

```
<Google> No UIViewController supplied to the ad. Cannot continue.
```

This is how my code looks:

initWithSize:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size { 
    if (...]) {
        ...

        self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
        self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-9147160832662960/2548046734";
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        // Requests test ads on simulators.
        [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

gameOver:

```
-(void)gameOver
{
    self.isGameOver = YES;
    ...

    if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
        self.interstitial.delegate = self;
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:_viewController];
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: So you need figure out what changes between the first game over and subsequent ones. The above code does nothing to pinpoint your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response @sangony, I've spent hours at this and I'm unable to locate where the issue is coming from. The above code is taking place in my GameScene.m, not in my ViewController.m. Nowhere else in my code is _viewController being changed so I'm not sure as to why it doesn't load any more ads after loading the first ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scene.viewController = self.viewController;
```

This is what was required to be added to the initWithSize in my GameScene.
Works perfectly now